# How to find an integral curve of an vector field

Tags: analysis, smooth-manifolds

This question is from my class notes on  manifolds and I was unable to solve it.

> Find the integral curve starting at $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ of the vector field $X= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}  + x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and find the largest interval where it is defined.

The problem I am facing is that in my notes there is not even 1 example on how to find integral curve.

So, I am really confused. The definition is: Let $X\in \chi(M)$. A smooth curve $\sigma : (a,b)\to M$ is an integral curve of X starting at p if $\sigma'(t)=X_{\sigma(t)}$, $0\in (a,b)$. $\sigma(0)=p$.

I tried to find some examples on internet but could not really find much related to manifolds  although there is a lot of stuff related to differential equations.

I shall be really thankful if you can help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you are able to construct an integral curve $\sigma: \left( - \epsilon, \epsilon \right) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. Then, $\sigma = \left( \sigma_1, \sigma_2 \right)$, where $\sigma_1, \sigma_2: \left( - \epsilon, \epsilon \right) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are smooth maps. Moreover, by the definition of an integral curve, we must have $\sigma' \left( t \right) = X_{\sigma \left( t \right)} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} + \sigma_1 \left( t \right) \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}$. On the other hand, by the definition of derivative of a curve, we have $\sigma' \left( t \right) = \sigma_1' \left( t \right) \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} + \sigma_2' \left( t \right) \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}$.

That is, we get a system of differential equations:

$$\sigma_1' \left( t \right) = 1,$$
$$\sigma_2' \left( t \right) = \sigma_1 \left( t \right).$$

Also, the integral curve we want is the one which passes through $\left( a, b \right)$, so that we have the initial conditions $\sigma_1 \left( 0 \right) = a$ and $\sigma_2 \left( 0 \right) = b$. Now can you solve the IVP to get the integral curve?

Comment: Great answer , ty!